# API Gateway doesn't pass headers to Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am trying to make a multipart http query through API Gateway to a Lambda. I have set the binary media type to 'multipart/form-data'. The issue is that I need to access the Content-Type header, so that I can parse the body correctly in my lambda logic.

But when I console log the lambda event, I can see that the Content-Type header is missing, even though I can see that it is well sent by my client.

Also, everything works perfectly in local with serverless-offline, without going through API Gateway.

So I'm guessing API Gateway does its own processing of my request and send a different version of it to my Lambda, with different headers.

How can I force API Gateway to pass this header to my Lambda ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the integration request try adding an HTTP Header `Content-Type` mapped from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Then add a mapping template for `multipart/form-data`

```
{
    "Content-Type" : "$input.params('Content-Type')",
    "body_base64" : "$util.base64Encode($input.body)"
}
```

If you are using an **OpenAPI** template to create the api with terraform or serverless then configure the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration:` node

```
requestTemplates:
  multipart/form-data: "{\n    \"Content-Type\"\
    \ : \"$input.params('Content-Type')\",\n    \"body_base64\" : \"$util.base64Encode($input.body)\"\
    \n}"
passthroughBehavior: "never"
type: "aws"
```

Comment: Would you know how to do that from the sdk with serverless framework ?

Comment: You can add it as part of the OpenAPI spec in yaml